# background highlight issue with theme applied

Tags: android, android-theme

If I apply a theme to my app, the background highlight looks off.  However, it looks fine without a theme applied:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row_item_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_item_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/podcast_row_item_count"
        style="@style/podcast_list_unread_count"
        android:background="@drawable/list_unread_count_circle"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/podcast_row_item_thumbnail"
        style="@style/podcast_list_title"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.setTheme(R.style.AMOLED);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}

<style name="Main" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
</style>

<style name="AMOLED" parent="Main">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#aeaeae</item>
</style>

<resources>
    <color name="wc_background_amoled">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, the solution is to use this: `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`